# Css Accordion focusing issue

Tags: html, css

The anchor tags are placing the targeted content, at the top of the screen. I need to figure out a way to counter this by making the screen and the content stay in place rather than jumping about.

Css

```
/* -- >> accordion box << -- */  
.accordion {
width:640px;
overflow:hidden;
margin:10px;
color:#FFF;
padding:10px;
position: relative;
}

/* -- >> accordian head styles << -- */
/* -- >> Set style of open slide << -- */
.accordion section:target {
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
padding-top: 1em;
padding-right: 1em;
padding-bottom: 2em;
padding-left: 1em;
}
.accordion section:target:hover {
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
.accordion section:target h2 {
width:100%;
}
.accordion section:target h2 a {
color:#CCC;
padding:0;
}
.accordion section:target p {
display:block;
}
.accordion section h2 a {
padding:8px 10px;
display:block;
font-size:16px;
font-weight:normal;
color:#FFF;
text-decoration:none;
}

/* -- >> set style of closed slide << -- */
.accordion section {
float:left;
overflow:hidden;
color:#FFF;
cursor:pointer;
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
margin:3px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.accordion section:hover {
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
.accordion section p {
display:none;
}
.accordion section:after {
position:relative;
font-size:24px;
color:#FFF;
font-weight:bold;
}
.accordion section:nth-child(1):after {
content:'';
}
.accordion section:nth-child(2):after {
content:'';
}
.accordion section:nth-child(3):after {
content:'';
}
.accordion section:nth-child(4):after {
content:'';
}
.accordion section:nth-child(5):after {
content:'';
}

/* -- >> Vertical << -- */
.vertical section {
width:100%;
height:40px;
-webkit-transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
-moz-transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
-o-transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
-ms-transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
}
/* -- >> Set height of the slide << -- */
.vertical :target {
height:250px;
width:97%;
}
.vertical section h2 {
position:relative;
left:0;
top:-15px;
}
/* -- >> Set position of the number on the slide << -- */
.vertical section:after {
top:-60px;
left:810px;
}
.vertical section:target:after {
left:-9999px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="accordion vertical">
      <section id="vertone">
          <h2><a href="#vertone">About Us</a></h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse id lobortis massa. Nunc viverra velit leo, sit amet elementum mi. Fusce posuere nunc a mi tempus malesuada. Curabitur facilisis rhoncus eros eget placerat. Aliquam semper mauris sit amet justo tempor nec lacinia magna molestie. Etiam placerat congue dolor vitae adipiscing. Aliquam ac erat lorem, ut iaculis justo. Etiam mattis dignissim gravida. Aliquam nec justo ante, non semper mi. Nulla consectetur interdum massa, vel porta enim vulputate sed. Maecenas elit quam, egestas eget placerat non, fringilla vel eros. Nam vehicula elementum nulla sed consequat. Phasellus eu erat enim. Praesent at magna non massa dapibus scelerisque in eu lorem.<br/></p>
      </section>
      <section id="verttwo">
          <h2><a href="#verttwo">Services</a></h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse id lobortis massa. Nunc viverra velit leo, sit amet elementum mi. Fusce posuere nunc a mi tempus malesuada. Curabitur facilisis rhoncus eros eget placerat. Aliquam semper mauris sit amet justo tempor nec lacinia magna molestie. Etiam placerat congue dolor vitae adipiscing. Aliquam ac erat lorem, ut iaculis justo. Etiam mattis dignissim gravida. Aliquam nec justo ante, non semper mi. Nulla consectetur interdum massa, vel porta enim vulputate sed. Maecenas elit quam, egestas eget placerat non, fringilla vel eros. Nam vehicula elementum nulla sed consequat. Phasellus eu erat enim. Praesent at magna non massa dapibus scelerisque in eu lorem.<br/></p>
      </section>
      <section id="vertthree">
          <h2><a href="#vertthree">Blog</a></h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse id lobortis massa. Nunc viverra velit leo, sit amet elementum mi. Fusce posuere nunc a mi tempus malesuada. Curabitur facilisis rhoncus eros eget placerat. Aliquam semper mauris sit amet justo tempor nec lacinia magna molestie. Etiam placerat congue dolor vitae adipiscing. Aliquam ac erat lorem, ut iaculis justo. Etiam mattis dignissim gravida. Aliquam nec justo ante, non semper mi. Nulla consectetur interdum massa, vel porta enim vulputate sed. Maecenas elit quam, egestas eget placerat non, fringilla vel eros. Nam vehicula elementum nulla sed consequat. Phasellus eu erat enim. Praesent at magna non massa dapibus scelerisque in eu lorem.<br/></p>
      </section>
      <section id="vertfour">
          <h2><a href="#vertfour">Portfolio</a></h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse id lobortis massa. Nunc viverra velit leo, sit amet elementum mi. Fusce posuere nunc a mi tempus malesuada. Curabitur facilisis rhoncus eros eget placerat. Aliquam semper mauris sit amet justo tempor nec lacinia magna molestie. Etiam placerat congue dolor vitae adipiscing. Aliquam ac erat lorem, ut iaculis justo. Etiam mattis dignissim gravida. Aliquam nec justo ante, non semper mi. Nulla consectetur interdum massa, vel porta enim vulputate sed. Maecenas elit quam, egestas eget placerat non, fringilla vel eros. Nam vehicula elementum nulla sed consequat. Phasellus eu erat enim. Praesent at magna non massa dapibus scelerisque in eu lorem.<br/></p>
      </section>
      <section id="vertfive">
          <h2><a href="#vertfive">Contact</a></h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse id lobortis massa. Nunc viverra velit leo, sit amet elementum mi. Fusce posuere nunc a mi tempus malesuada. Curabitur facilisis rhoncus eros eget placerat. Aliquam semper mauris sit amet justo tempor nec lacinia magna molestie. Etiam placerat congue dolor vitae adipiscing. Aliquam ac erat lorem, ut iaculis justo. Etiam mattis dignissim gravida. Aliquam nec justo ante, non semper mi. Nulla consectetur interdum massa, vel porta enim vulputate sed. Maecenas elit quam, egestas eget placerat non, fringilla vel eros. Nam vehicula elementum nulla sed consequat. Phasellus eu erat enim. Praesent at magna non massa dapibus scelerisque in eu lorem.<br/></p>
      </section>
    </div>
```

**[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rLtBT/2/)** Basic example of how the accordion works. On a side note is there a way to make the sections close by clicking on them again?

Comment: As it is a pure css accordion, you need to add to your anchors `onclick="return false"`

Comment: @Pete Adding `onclick="return false"` appears to have broken the links completly. :/

Comment: I guess it's because it causes the section not to be targeted, the thing with pure css is that you are at the whim of the browser and as you are clicking on a link it will take you to where the link is pointing so if the section is not at the top of the page, it will be scrolled to the top.  If you are wanting to go the pure css route a dirty workaround could be to put it in a frame the size of the accordion so that it wouldn't cause the parent page to jump

Comment: For closing it again, I only know of the somewhat dirty trick of working with checkboxes and target (since you can check/uncheck them).. (if you want pure CSS that is)

Comment: Understandibly, of course. However can see now that the link is targeting the section ID's. and by doing so placing screen focus on the attached section. If I can figure out how to target the sections but not place them in focus, the problem should be sorted.

Comment: @Goombah I'll take what I can get, and Iron out the kinks later. :)

Comment: The problem is that the css `:target` pseudo-element works on the # that is in the url so it will always jump to the section with that id.

Comment: @Beaniie http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/02/21/accordion-with-css3/

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/on-target/ also has some ideas for workarounds

Comment: @Pete Can `onclick=""`handle, normal html elements, or is it purly a tool for script interfacing?

Comment: I think it is for firing js functions only

Comment: @Goombah Thats a good read, I'll test a few things out and if need be I'll return here.

Comment: @Pete if crunch comes to crunch, I'll pull the CSS accordion and implement a Jquery one. But for now I'll keep looking into working it out. Ill post the answer back here when I do. Thanks Again!